# Read Keys from JSON output using jq

Tags: jq

Have a JSON output as below. Trying to extract only key names like "key-user" and "oidc-cid" using JQ

```
[
  {
    "key-user": {
      "contentType": "",
      "enabled": true,
      "isSecret": true,
      "value": null
    },
    "oidc-cid": {
      "contentType": "",
      "enabled": true,
      "isSecret": true,
      "value": null
    }
  }
]
```

Tried the following command

```
jq 'keys' and jq 'keys[]' and jq '[] | keys'
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the dot in last command

```
jq '.[]|keys' data.json
[
  "key-user",
  "oidc-cid"
]
```